# Is the Sefer Hachinuch actually about reasons for mitzvos?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, taamei-mitzvot-reasons

(Inspired by the answers given by @רבות מחשבות and @mevaqesh to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/88036/resource-on-reasons-intention-for-mitzvot).)

When people speak about reasons for mitzvos they generally mean something along the lines of "God commanded us to do this because..." or "God commanded us to do this in order that..."

Accordingly, is the Sefer Hachinuch actually about the reasons **for** mitzvos, or is it really about the reasons **to do** mitzvos? Here are a few citations from within the work that seem to indicate that his purpose in writing the work and listing the "shorshei hamitzvos" was mainly to convince the youth of the benefits of doing mitzvos.

Mitzvah 117

> שרשי מצוה זו נעלמים מאד למצוא אפילו רמז קטן מהן ואולם מפני שכבר הודעתי
>   בפתח דברי שכוונתי באלו הטעמים שאני כותב להרגיל הנערים ולהטעים להם
>   בתחילת בואם לשמוע דברי ספר כי יש לדברי התורה טעמים ותועלות ויקבלום על
>   דרך ההרגל שלהם וכפי חולשת שכלם ואל יהיו להם המצוות בתחילה כדברי הספר
>   החתום פן יבעטו בהם מתוך כך בנערותם ויניחום לעולם וילכו בהבל על כן
>   אכתוב בהם כל אשר יעלה בתחילת המחשבה ואל יתפוש עלי תופש בשום דבר אחרי
>   ידע הכוונה

Epilogue to Sefer Vayikra

> והנני עודני בא להזכירך במה שהתנצלתי הרבה פעמים על השרשים אשר מלאני לני
>   לכתוב נמצות שאין הכונה רק לחנך הנערים ולתת אל לבם כי יש במצות תועלות
>   רבות גלויות לכל אדם כאשר יוכלון הבין בילדותם ועל כן קראתי שם הספר
>   חינוך ועומק חכמתם ורוב תועלתם אם יזכו ישיגו בם בימי זקנתם הלא ידעת כי
>   יש פרי נמצא אשר בו כמה תרופות בסגולה וגם טוב לאכלה ואיש חכם יודע לבפר
>   בשבחי תרופותיו ואשר לא ידע בכל אלה יאמר שהוא טוב לאוכליו

Mitzvah 440

> וזה נאמר אל הילדים עד אשר יגדלו בחכמה ויבינו בכל דברי התורה סודות
>   נפלאים

Mitzvah 545

> והנה הארכתי לכתוב לך בני כל זה להעיד על כל שרשי ספרי עדים נאמנים שני
>   עמודי עולם חכמים גדולים ונבונים בעלי שכל מזוקק ובסתרי התורה מקובלים כי
>   הנך רואה בעיניך דעת שניהם כי יש במצוות התורה טעם להועיל בני אדם
>   בדעותיהם להכשירם ולהרגילם להכשיר בהן כל פעולותיהם ושאין התועלת בעשייתן
>   חלילה לבורא ברוך הוא ואם אמנם כי יש מן המצוות שלא השגנו בטעמן במיעוט
>   שכלנו מרוב עומקן ותכלית גודלן לא נמנע ממנו מהגיד בהן כל אשר נשיג למצוא
>   מן התועלת שיש לו לאדם בעשייתן וזה דרכי בכל שיחתי בספרי זה שיש במצוות
>   תועלת מצוי לנו אך לא אל המצוה בהן ואם תתן לבך בדברים תמצא זאת הכוונה
>   בכולן והרבה יגעתי במקצתן להשיג בעניות דעתי לראות בהן מעט קט מרוב
>   התועלות שבהן וכתבתיו על כל אחת וזה חלקי מכל עמל

To clarify, I am not saying that the Sefer Hachinuch simply doesn't believe his "reasons" to necessarily be the definitive reasons. Rambam would say the same thing about his own "reasons". Rather I am trying to contrast the Sefer Hachinuch with Rambam, to say that Rambam is giving reasons **for** the mitzvos while the Sefer Hachinuch is mainly giving benefits of the mitzvos (i.e. reasons **to do** mitzvos).

Comment: If anyone has a good translation of Sefer Hachinuch, feel free to add it for the excerpts. The only one I found was not very impressive so I left it out.

Comment: To clarify the two sides;1)are the reasons why hashem wants us to do them. 2)what benefits or effect does it have on us. Is this what you mean?

Comment: I wouldn't quite call it "the reasons why Hashem wants us to do them" because my question is independent of an entire philosophical discussion of what it means for Hashem to "want something". I would refer to the two sides as 1) the stated purpose/goal of the mitzvah 2) any benefits of the mitzvah that would be a reason for someone to fulfill it. For example, I could say that the stated purpose/goal of charity is to alleviate poverty but a benefit that might convince someone to give charity is that he will feel good about helping someone.

Comment: In philosophical works (i.e. not kabbalah or chassidut), mitzvot are only for us (how they help us improve, etc.), not for G-d. If so, all the reasons for the mitzvot are only how we benefit from them.